# How do I eliminate "uninteresting" parts of waveform from a non-uniform waveform using MATLAB functions?

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning, signal-processing, modulation

I have signal(s) (of a person climbing stairs.) of the following nature. This is a signal worth 38K + samples over a period of 6 minutes of stair ascent. The parts where there is some **low frequency noise** are the times when the person **would take a turnabout** to get to the next flight of stairs (**and hence does not count as stair ascent**.)

[image] 
Figure 1

This is why I need to get rid of it for my deep learning model which only accepts the stair ascent data. Essentially, I only need the high frequency regions where the person is climbing stairs. I could do eliminate it manually, but it would take me a lot of time since there are 58 such signals.

My approach for a solution to this problem was modulating this signal with a square wave which is 0 for low frequency regions and 1 for high frequency regions and then to multiply the signals together. But the problem is how to create such a square wave signal which detects the high and low frequency regions on its own?

I tried enveloping the signal (using MATLAB's envelope rms function) and I got the following result:

[image] 
Figure 2

As you can see the envelope rms signal follows the function quite well. But I am stuck as to how to create a modulating square wave function off of it (essentially what I am asking for a **variable** pulse-width modulating waveform.)

PS: I have considered using high-pass filter but this won't work because there are some low frequency signals in the high frequency stair-climbing region which I cannot afford to remove. I have also thought of using some form of rising/falling edge detection(for the envelope rms function) but have found no practical way of implementing it.) Please advise.

Thank you for your help in advance,
Shreya

Thanks to David for his thresholding suggestion which I did on my dataset I have these results... though I am again stuck with trying to get rid of the redundant peaks between zeros (see image below) What do I do next?

[image]
Figure 3

I think I have been able to solve my problem of being able to isolate the "interesting" part of the waveform from the entire original waveform successfully using the following procedure (for the reader's future reference:)

A non-uniform waveform such as Figure 1 can have the "envelope(rms)" MATLAB function applied to obtain the orange function such as the one in Figure 2. Subsequently, I filtered this enveloperms waveform using MATLAB's very own "idfilt" function. This enabled me to get rid of the unwanted spikes (between zeroes) that were occurring between the "interesting" parts of the waveform. Then, using thresholding, I converted this waveform to be equal to 1 at the "interesting" parts and 0 at the "uninteresting" parts giving me a **pulse-width modulated** square wave form that follows ONLY the "interesting parts of the original waveform (in Figure 1) I then multiplied my square waveform with the original function and was able to filter out the "uninteresting" parts as demonstrated in Figure 4.

[image]
Figure 4

Thank You all for your help! This thread is now resolved!

Comment: Have you tried using a high-pass filter? I think it would have better performance and should be easier to implement.

Comment: Please don't confuse link descriptions with alt-text. The thing in square brackets is what will replace the image when it can't be shown. Don't use it for prose.

Comment: @MadPhysicist haha sorry this is the first question I ever posted. but thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: @HeladioAmaya Please see my "PS:" comment... this explains why I can't simply use a high-pass filter :(

Comment: Can you simply remove observations when the value of the envelope is below some threshold? That's a simple indexing operation `data(envelope<threshold) = []` (in Matlab).

Comment: @David I was about to try it because you are right this may be the only way to do it... though, the main issue with this suggestion is that some of the low frequency region data-points may cross the threshold (and this would involve me to do some more tweaking and is not the most automated implementation) :( but thanks for sharing your suggestion which I may use as an alternative option :D

Comment: Could you share the data you show such that one has some data to test? Furthermore, could you filter this data manually to show what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @PatrickHappel Please see my edits that show the desired output which I have achieved already. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question please write it up as an answer and accept it. That way future users of the site who see your question in a search will know it has a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have been able to solve my problem of being able to isolate the "interesting" part of the waveform from the entire original waveform successfully using the following procedure (for the reader's future reference:)

A non-uniform waveform such as Figure 1 can have the "envelope(rms)" MATLAB function applied to obtain the orange function such as the one in Figure 2. Subsequently, I filtered this enveloperms waveform using MATLAB's very own "idfilt" function. This enabled me to get rid of the unwanted spikes (between zeroes) that were occurring between the "interesting" parts of the waveform. Then, using thresholding, I converted this waveform to be equal to 1 at the "interesting" parts and 0 at the "uninteresting" parts giving me a **pulse-width modulated** square wave form that follows ONLY the "interesting parts of the original waveform (in Figure 1) I then multiplied my square waveform with the original function and was able to filter out the "uninteresting" parts as demonstrated in Figure 4.

Thank You all for your help! This thread is now resolved!